# Check for running fullTrustProcess UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a dotnet core fullTrustProcess console app running on startup packaged with my main UWP app. the UWP app relies of this console app as kind of a communications server. There is an issue, if the Console App is somehow terminated then the "still running" UWP app is suddenly broken!

It seems using:
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName() 
is illegal in UWP so then how on earth can you see if the process is dead and again call:
        await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();

to start it and keep the entire application functioning correctly?

Is you can start a fullTrustProcess in UWP but are forbidden to check for it or terminate it then that is a design flaw in my opinion, even if deliberate.

Comment: Don't you have any inter-process communication available to ping your process?

Comment: If the console app is connected via AppServiceConnection you will get a TaskCancelled event when the console app goes away. Would that work for your scenario?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT is there any straighht to the point docs on this that you can point me towards? It is just a dotnetcore app launched by UWp in full trust. Grrr I swear this is my last time developing on UWP. Win32 all the way! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When your console companion app goes away you will receive a TaskCanceled event on your AppService task that handles the connection between your UWP and the fulltrust process.

In that even you can then decide whether or not you want to re-launch the companion process.

I have a complete sample for this scenario on my blog. See the "Handling Process Exit Scenarios" section on this post:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Comment: Wick MSFT thanks but cannot 100% follow the examp0les because once again MSFT docs are fragmented, all I want to do is subscribe to the .NetCore "companion app" terminated event and then relaunch it, simple task in theory but UWP makes it complicated. I tried from the examples but not working, maybe I missed something. Thanks